Prove that $N_f(xz) \leq N_f(x) + N_f(z)$
Let $f: G \to \mathbb{R}$ a bounded function defined on a group $G$. Define the function $N_f$ on $G$ given by $N_f(x) = \sup\{|f(yx) - f(y)| : y \in G\}$, and prove that $N_f(x\cdot z) \leq N_f(x) + N_f(z)$. I'm trying to prove this inequality, but when I start with the left hand side, it appears a $f(yxz)$ and I don't know how to get rid of this, and if I start from the right hand side, I can't manipulate it to show some $f(y(xz))$. Some tips?
Edit:
\begin{align*}
N_f(xz) & = \sup|f(y(xz) - f(y)|\\
& = \sup|f((yx)z) - f(y) + f(yx) - f(yx)|\\
& \leq \sup|f((yx)z) - f(yx)| + \sup|f(yx) - f(y)|\\
& = N_f(z) + N_f(x)
\end{align*}
My doubt is in the end, when I consider $N_f(z) = \sup|f((yx)z) - f(yx)|$, my thought is that $yx$ run all over $G$, and by closure this is valid. Is this right?

Write $f(yxz)-f(y)$ as $f(yxz)-f(yx)+f(yx)-f(y)$ and use the triangle inequality for real numbers. Then observe that iterating over all $y\in G$ is the same as iterating over $yx$ for all $y\in G.$
After edit of original question:
Yes, this is valid. The supremum is independent of the order in which the group elements are considered.

This point was exactly my doubt
